# Include models in other script

Tags: node.js

I want to have a global script that I can include system wide for some helper files.

This is the helper file (helper.js):

```
async function hasStock() {

}

// Export it to make it available outside
module.exports.hasStock = hasStock;
```

But now the problem, I have a model that I give in the index.js, the model is only available there:

```
app.use('/api/parts', require('./routes/part.js')(app, models));
```

But I also need that model (models) at my helper.js file.

So I thought I need to do this in part.js (from /api/parts):

```
module.exports = function (app, models) {

    require("../helpers/helper.js")(models);
}
```

But that isn't also good I think. What is a good solution to include the models (models object only available in the index.js) and to use this system wide in helpers.js?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to export the function `hasStock` by following method ,

In your **helper.js** file

```
const anyObjectName = {
    hasStock : async function hasStock {

    }
}
//like this export , you can use this object and it's function anywhere . 
module.exports = anyObjectName;
```

In your **part.js (from /api/parts):**

```
    var anyObjectName = require('../helpers/helper.js');

       //now you can access the hasStock function in part.js file like

    anyObjectName.hasStock();
```

Hope it is useful for your and solves your problem .